# Slash in background property in scss file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

In scss file I have background property that does not work. How can I escape it?

```
.flag  {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(image-path("flags/uk.png")) no-repeat scroll left 22px top 9px / 20px auto;
}
```

This works

```
.flag  {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(image-path("flags/uk.png")) no-repeat scroll left 22px top 9px;
}
```

Update - Adding part of the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'pg'

gem 'haml'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'upmin-admin'

#### Access Control
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'rolify'

#### Assets
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
```

Update 2 
Compiled outputs. First with slash and second without

```
.flag {
}

.flag {
    background: url("/assets/flags/uk-51b83957b8e40b69605fd32329ecab0a14f9a51ab98af407b8335ed461d88e4f.png") no-repeat scroll left 22px top 9px transparent;
}
```

Update 3 Reverted to long notation. Though this is not the answer for the problem.

```
.flag{
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:left 22px top 9px;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: 20px auto;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce with any version of Sass: http://sassmeister.com/gist/18259bf0234296c6683b

Comment: It goes through the Ruby on Rails assets pipeline. Maybe that is the way to reproduce.

Comment: Are you certain you're not running some sort of post-processor on your compiled results?  Sass will not output empty selectors like that at all (see: http://sassmeister.com/gist/cade239689ecf610c3b9).